Azure Databricks endpoint 404 from PowerApps
I have a custom connector in PowerApps that I am trying to use to POST some JSON data to an Azure Databricks endpoint. But I am getting following HTTP 404 response. I tried the same from Postman and it is working fine. There are no issues in URL. Also I removed special characters from the endpoint name to rule out any possible issue.
{
  "error_code": "ENDPOINT_NOT_FOUND",
  "message": "Path must be of form /serving-endpoints/<endpoint_name>/invocations or /serving-endpoints/<endpoint_name>/served-models/<served_model_name>/invocations"
}

Request:
Headers:
{
  "Authorization": "Bearer asdoandnfoadnfdonfsoanfanfioebfoen",
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "Accept": "application/json"
}

Body:
{
    "abc": {
        "def": [
            "ghi",
            "jklm"
        ],
        "data": [
            [
                122.90031412633925,
                198.7474380884414
            ],
            [
                122.90031412633925,
                78.33542851039341
            ]
        ]
    }
}


Can you provide your flow configurations for better understanding of the issue?

@RakeshGovindula Please see my answer. Thanks for your time.

This error was due to incorrect configuration. In "General" tab, I had added the endpoint path in Base part of URL. And then in "Definition" tab, while specifying request format, I had provided complete URL (host/path). So eventual request was going to host/path/path, which didn't exist.
Also, I struggled a lot because make.powerapps.com was not showing me what URL was actually called (even in debug window), and there was nothing in Azure log. I stumbled upon an article which specified correct way to configure.
Correct config:

